# What's the Internet Explorer keyboard shortcut to select "Save as" from the "Do you want to open or save ... from ...?"-dialog?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer

**Context**

This dialog has a dropdown next to the `Save` button where you can select `Save as`.

[image]
[Image source](http://static.spiceworks.com/shared/post/0003/2964/right1.png).

Imagine that the keyboard focus was somewhere on the web page, not on `Cancel` as depicted in the screenshot.

**Question**

How do you get to the `Save as` menu entry with a keyboard shortcut?

It goes like <kbd>Something</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, but I don't remember what the <kbd>Something</kbd> was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Alt+N will focus on the Notification bar.
2. Tab will move to Save.
3. Press Down.
4. Press "a".

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F6</kbd> will cycle between focusing on your URL bar, the web page, and finally the dialogue box which you desire.